# Arch Linux - DHCP - Can someone diagnose this?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, installation, arch-linux, dhcp

Arch Linux Wifi Connection Issues

I am currently in the process of trying to install Arch i686 on an Acer Aspire One 532h (32 bit).

At this point I am still in the LiveCD environment and setting up the wireless connection. However, I am running into a problem with connectivity.

I guess I should say that I have already verified the compatibility for my network adapter. 
Atheros AR9285
http://www.linuxquestions.org/hcl/showproduct.php/product/4446/cat/160

Also verified it from the Arch command line:

```
#lspci -k

02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
...
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Kernel modules: ath9k


# iw dev
```

says my interface is wlp2s0 (it's the only interface available)

when i try to use:

```
# wifi-menu
```

I can select my SSID and enter my password and save the profile

```
# ip link show wlp2s0

3: wlp2s0: <NO CARRIER, BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP> mtu 1500.......

# dhcpcd wlp2s0

dhcpcd[2191] version 6.4.2 starting
...   [2198] wlp2s0: starting wpa_supplicant
...   [2201] wlp2s0: failed to start wpa_supplicant
Line 1144: unknown EAP method 'SIM'
...
...
dhcpcd[2520]: wlp2s0: waiting for carrier
dhcpcd[2520]: timed out
dhcpcd[2520]: exited
```

I also created a file at /etc/wpa_supplicant/test.conf very simple consisting of basically the SSID and password not mentioning an EAP, WPA, WEP or any protocol.

```
 # wpa_supplicant -B -i wlp2s0 -c <(wpa_supplicant/test.conf)
```

Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant

```
 # dhcpcd wlp2s0
```

(I get the same error message as earlier.)

Not sure what I can do at this point. I verified the .sig on the ISO, verified that my network card is supported. Used the simple interface (wifi-menu), used the CLI to create a .conf and execute the wpa_supplicant manually. I am getting a hangup at the dhcp somewhere but not sure where I need to look to diagnose this problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you used wifi-menu there is no need to create your own wpa_supplicant config file. wifi-menu will handle this. Basically after you run `wifi-menu wlp2s0`you should have a connection. Did you start it like this?

Comment: Of course, I am fairly basic and I chose the easy way but when that failed I started to dig deeper on my own. Is there something I can change in the DHCP setting? How could I get there? Oh, also, not sure if this has any bearing but, initially my wifi connection was hidden. After I looked at the wifi-menu GUI, I didn't see an option for this. I exited and changed my wifi setting to visible then went back to wifi-menu and selected my wifi access point. Could that cause a misconfiguration?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the channel mode to `auto`. Before you do that make sure your wifi interface is down. After that, turn it back up. Solution found [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration#Failed_to_get_IP_address).

```
$ ip link set wlp2s0 down    
$ iwconfig wlp2s0 channel auto
$ ip link set wlp2s0 up
```

Also just for your information if you are using Arch Linux for the first time: The Arch Wiki is extremely helpfull and almost everything is covered + troubleshoot for a lot of problems. It is the best Wiki for a Linux destribution. Worth a look! [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/)

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try and see what happens. Actually, I do read the wiki (probably too much) and I am often overwhelmed with possibilities. I figured I could ask someone more experienced than I before I try every option available and end up making things worse. :)

Comment: No luck. After this, I tried to reconnect using wifi-menu and I am getting an error "Job for netctl@wlp2s0\x2networkname.service failed. See 'systemctl status netctl......service and 'journalctl -xn' for details. Hmmm... I will look it up and see what I find.

Comment: I got it. I just rebooted deleted the /mnt/home directory. Then ran wifi-menu immediately and now I am getting a ping back from www.google.com. :) I guess I added too many steps and made it more complicated than it had to be. Thanks again for your help.